# Sorting strings from prompt is not working but it works when hard coded

Tags: javascript

My code is not working when I give the value via prompt but is working with hard coded input.

Could someone please help me understand why that is?

```
var str=prompt("Enter String :: ");
alert(selectionSort(str));

function selectionSort(items){
    var len = items.length,
        min;

    for (i=0; i < len; i++){
        min = i;

        //check the rest of the array to see if anything is smaller
        for (j=i+1; j < len; j++){
            if (items[j] < items[min]){
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != min){
            swap(items, i, min);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

This is my swapping function:

```
function swap(items, firstIndex, secondIndex){
    var temp = items[firstIndex];
    items[firstIndex] = items[secondIndex];
    items[secondIndex] = temp;
}
```

Comment: What is your code trying to do exactly? Sort the characters in `str`?

Comment: yes i input some string e.g "farhan"
my code need to sort in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the characters you can use:

```
var str = "farhan";
var sorted = str.split("").sort().join("");
console.log(sorted); // "aafhnr"
```

`.split("")` turns the string into an array. `.sort` sorts the array (default is ascending order) and `.join("")` turns the array back into a string.

For educational purposes it might be useful to write your own sort routine, but beyond that, use the built in functions as much as you can.